# How to include a range of values in a scatter plot using 'matplotlib'?

Tags: python, csv, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I am trying to plot a range of values from 2 columns of a '.csv' file, but 'matplotlib' doesn't consider the entire range I've defined. I've used this code:

```
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 raw_data = pd.read_csv('tripdata_2015.csv')
 tip_amounts = raw_data['tip_amount']
 trip_IDs = raw_data['trip_IDs']

 fig = plt.figure()
 plt.scatter(trip_IDs[-1000:], tip_amounts[-1000:])
 plt.show()
```

and don't know why the plot only includes few values, since all the range I've defined contains real values that should appear in the plot.

I've already tried `figsize`, `.xlim()` and using `seaborn` but the result is the same. I just get a plot of bigger size with the same few values.

Any idea of how to solve it?

Comment: Maybe indexes have to be positive in `plt.scatter(...)`?

Comment: What is the length of trip_IDs[-1000:]? Check for repeated values

Comment: Well indexes are positive, I'm just considering a subset of the trip_IDs as its length is over 12 million.

Comment: Add a few print statements, I would.  Does it work for a minimal example? Have you tried to just plot some synthetic data?  Also check out [mcve].

Comment: print out the lengths of the arrays, to make sure you get 1000 for each as expected. Print out `pd.isnull(trip_IDs[-1000:]).sum()` (and also for the second array), to see if any null values exist. Also, as @JensMunk suggested, if you have duplicates of (x,y) pairs, you'll only see a single point on the plot, especially if the range is big (which will cause neighboring points to visually cluster into a single point).